# Conditional formatting, matching a specific text in one cell to change the colour of another cell with variables

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm building a Darts Team Ladder that needs to be able to highlight (Cell background color) of two teams that have played on a specific board on a specific week. But due to looking at it too long and going around in circles, I need some expert advice.

I have a Ladder

[image: Ladder]

And I have the Fixture sheet

[image: Fixture Sched]

What I want to do is display a background color on the 'Ladder' sheet from the data on the 'Fixture Sched' sheet. The Home and Away teams playing on Board 1 in a green color in Week 1, and on Board 2 in a blue color in Week 1, so forth and so forth for the 6 Boards. I will need to do this across the whole 22 Weeks.

Each Cell on the Ladder is pulling Data from another sheet, but this should not be an issue as I'm just trying to do some funky Conditional formatting to change the color based on this info, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A manual colouring of expected results may be helpful.  where is the schedule for the second and third week and so on?

Comment: Hi Ed, Yeah, I use to use a colouring for the result, but for some reason everyone found it confusing, lol, they requested that it shows a highlighted color so they know who played who on the night. On the 'Fixture Sched' sheet, columns H and I are the schedule, 'H' column being the Home side, and 'I' column being the Away side, column 'J' being the Board number, there is a blank row between each week, I did not list the date, or list the week numbers as I have that all configured on another sheet called 'Fixture', this sheet is just the raw data I was wishing to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the quick and dirty.  I am in a bit of a rush at the moment after just looking at the clock.  So here is the formula.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A4,INDEX($B:$D,(COLUMN(B$3)-2)*7+19,1):INDEX($B:$D,(COLUMN(B$3)-2)*7+24,3),3,0)=1,0)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A4,INDEX($B:$D,(COLUMN(B$3)-2)*7+19,2):INDEX($B:$D,(COLUMN(B$3)-2)*7+24,3),2,0)=1,0)
```

You will need to create a conditional format rule for each board you have.  so according to your question 6 times.  each time you create the conditional format rule (use custom format or formula method), change the `=1` part of the formula to the next board number.  Apply a different colour for each board number/rule.

When you have created all the rules, apply them to the range of B4 to W15.

If you run into issues, try to have cell B4 selected when creating the rules.

I will be back in about 6 hours for edits if required.

**Update Required (after the 6 hours)**

according to Jeeped' previous answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081497/using-an-array-based-formula-in-conditional-formatting) you cannot use dynamic references in conditional formatting the way I did.  So on to solution number 2 with the use of `OFFSET`.  I was trying to avoid offset as it is a volatile function, meaning the formula recalculates anytime something in the workbook changes.  So if you use a lot of these formula, or in your case if you applied to to a large area, you may find your spreadsheet bogging down.  If it does you now know why.  I dont know where the magic number will be for this but I think 12*22*12 calculations will be peanuts and you should be ok.

So the first attempt at rectifying the situation was to convert the above formula to offset...and I wound up changing it somewhat and wound up with something that looked like this:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH($A4,OFFSET(Sheet2!$H$2,(COLUMN(B$3)-2)*7,0,6,1),0),MATCH($A4,OFFSET(Sheet2!$I$2,(COLUMN(B$3)-2)*7,0,6,1),0))=3
```

I had a slightly longer formula like the original but then I took a shortcut since your matches each weak were listed in order by dart board.  So while the above formula test true for finding teams that played on board 3 in the worksheet, it failed miserably in conditional formatting.  Which essentially prompted me to post my own question as to why it does not work since the individual formulas in it do work.

So your 12 formula work around solution for now is to repeat the following two formulas 6 times.  Once for each board:

```
=MATCH($A4,OFFSET(Sheet2!$H$2,(COLUMN(B$3)-2)*7,0,6,1),0)=1
=MATCH($A4,OFFSET(Sheet2!$I$2,(COLUMN(B$3)-2)*7,0,6,1),0)=1
```

Change the `=1` to 2, 3, 4, etc. for each board.  I would recommend having cell B4 (top left corner of your area) selected when entering your formulas.

- Copy the first formula to clipboard
- Select manage conditional formatting
- Select new rule
- Use a formula option and paste the formula in to the space
- Set your colour and any other formatting for board X
- Click 'ok'
- Do not hit apply when you get to the manage formula window, instead click new formula
- Repeat the process above and paste the formula you already have in clipboard
- Do this for all six boards
- Repeat the process from board 1 to board 6 with the second formula
- Make sure you assign the same colours to the same board for formula 2 (see bonus)

When that is all done and before you select apply, look at the box that the range applies to.  If you did not set it earlier it should say B4.  For one of the formulas change it to your desired range of B4:W15.  Then copy that range and apply it to each of the conditional formats you created.  Click apply finally.  Et voila!  You should have a board that looks something like the following:

[image]

Bonus points:

If you choose your colour shading right, you can have one colour for formula one like say dark red, and another colour like say light red for formula 2 and you would wind up with with the home team being the dark red and the away team being the light red.  works well when you do not have too many teams.  when you get too many teams it can get hard to tell the colour shades apart.

**Caveat:**
This works currently because your teams are listed in board order.  If the board order was in a random order the formula would need to change a little bit by adding an index portion in.

Comment: Hi Ed, I copied your formula into the 'Use a formula' section of conditional formatting, but it came back with an error before it would allow me to continue. Error being 'You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Conditional Formatting criteria'. At a guess, would it be because I am using Excel 2013? BTW, it shows how much I know about excel formulas, I can't even understand what is going on in that formula.. noob I am. I had B4 selected when trying to create the rule. Hope to hear from you soon :)

Comment: Yeah I ran into that issue and posted a question as to why my work around is not working.  I have a work around to that as well, but instead of needing 6 conditional formatting rules you would need 12. (2 x #boards)

Comment: I'm happy with 12 rules if you have that workaround available :) Then I can play with your formula and see how it works. lol. That's the best way for me to learn.

Comment: Fan friggin tastic Ed, works a Treat, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Marc, if the solution works for you and you feel its the best answer, remember to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Got it ... noob = me :)